# WSO2 Identity Server hangs after "Using java memory" line

Tags: networking, wso2, virtualbox

I had installed WSO2 Identity Server V5.2 on a VirtualBox machine, and it was working fine.

Then, I was doing some network testing/reconfiguration on my home network, where I was trying to separate my development (virtual) machines from my main in-home LAN by having the machine that was hosting VirtualBox connect wirelessly to a small router (a TPLink TL-WR702N) in a Bridge configuration, where the TPLink is connecting to my main WIFI network and then also exposing itself as a different WIFI network).

I was doing this testing because I am going to be working from a different location for awhile, and I wanted to isolate my dev machines while I was there and I only will have WIFI, and no hardwired connection, so I wanted to see if I could bridge wirelessly.

That machine hosting VBox started up ok and actually, the WSO2 machine also came up ok, but then when I tried to start the WSO2 IS (./wso2server.sh), it would output the 1st 3 lines and then hang on the 3rd line which was "User Java memory...".

If I move the hosting machine back to my normal LAN (i.e., not on the "bridged" network), everything works fine.

I noticed that when the hosting machine was on the bridged network, I couldn't ping the network gateway (192.168.0.1) from the VBox guest machines.

Would that cause the WSO2 to hang during startup?  What else might be causing this problem?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem was that WSO2 IS seems to need to be able to resolve the hostname during startup, and that was combined with needing to (apparently) bounce the machine to get the networking working.  After the bounce, the networking seemed to get straightened out and then the WSO2 IS was able start ok.